# Flatten JSON data file

Tags: json, jq

I'm a JQ newb, and have been wrestling with this task for while.
Our source JSON file looks like this...

```
[
{
  "id": "xxxx",
  "title": "xxxx",
  "created_at": "xxxx",
  "updated_at": "xxxx",
  "fields": [
    {
      "usernamevalue": "xxxx",
      "reference": "xxxx"
    },
    {
      "passwordvalue": "xxxx",
      "reference": "xxxx"
    },
    {
      "otherlabel": "xxxx",
      "otherreference": "xxxx"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "xxxx",
  "title": "xxxx",
  "created_at": "xxxx",
  "updated_at": "xxxx",
  "fields": [
    {
      "usernamevalue": "xxxx",
      "reference": "xxxx"
    },
    {
      "passwordvalue": "xxxx",
      "reference": "xxxx"
    },
    {
      "otherlabel": "xxxx",
      "otherreference": "xxxx"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

We are trying to end up with...

```
[
{
  "title": "xxxx",
  "updated_at": "xxxx",
  "usernamevalue": "xxxx",
  "passwordvalue": "xxxx"
},
{
  "title": "xxxx",
  "updated_at": "xxxx",
  "usernamevalue": "xxxx",
  "passwordvalue": "xxxx"
}
]
```

As such, the goals are...
End up with one, "flat" item for each entry -- so that we can then convert it to a CSV.
Only get the "title" and "updated_at" fields from the top level.
Only get fields with keys = "usernamevalue" and "passwordvalue" from the subordinate "fields" array, and move those fields to the top level.

Any guidance would be GREATLY appreciated!
(I've already spent more hours on this than I care to admit.)
THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `usernamevalue` and `passwordvalue` have only one occurrence as in your sample file, you can `add` the `fields` object, and then extract from it as you would with the outside keys:

```bash
jq 'map({id, updated_at} + (.fields | add | {usernamevalue, passwordvalue}))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "xxxx",
    "updated_at": "xxxx",
    "usernamevalue": "xxxx",
    "passwordvalue": "xxxx"
  },
  {
    "id": "xxxx",
    "updated_at": "xxxx",
    "usernamevalue": "xxxx",
    "passwordvalue": "xxxx"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ciHR06lwqo1)

---

If your ultimate goal is a CSV output of the values, you'd rather go for an array than an object, which could be something like:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | [.id, .updated_at, (.fields | add | .usernamevalue, .passwordvalue)] | @csv'
```

```json
"xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx"
"xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HP7Ia6PK04K)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the JSON object through their keys.

```
var jsonObject = [
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "field": [
        {
            "username": "john@gm.com",
            "context": "foob"
        }, 
        {
            "password": "kek",
            "context": "bar1"
        },
        {
            "other": "foobar",
            "context": "foobarbar"
        }
    ]
}
]

for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.field.length; i++)
{
    for(var key in jsonObject.field[i])
    {
        if(key == "username") 
        {
            jsonObject.usernamevalue = jsonObject.field[i].username;
        } else if(key == "password")
        {
            jsonObject.passwordvalue = jsonObjecct.field[i].password;
        }
    }
}

//Afterwards, you can delete the field 
delete jsonObject.field;
```